# Why do minimal polynomial have coefficients in the integral closured ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I'm reading the following theorem:
[image]

My question is, why are $a_i$s in $A[\alpha_1...\alpha_n]$?

Comment: The as are the result of evaluating the elementary symmetric functions on the alphas.

Comment: I guess I know the answer now...how stupid I am...

Comment: I suggest you write a complete answer answering your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an $\sigma$ sending $\alpha$ to $\alpha_i$ fixing $K$, hence $\alpha_i$ are integral over $A$ since $\alpha$ is, the rest is easy.